# HDMI Audio output in FGLRX

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound, ati, hdmi

Just made the transition to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I use my laptop as a gaming machine on the rare occasion and as a media streamer therefore I use it via HDMI on my TV.

After the transition to Linux, i installed AMD drivers thinking this would bring HDMI support into my setup. I am seeing an extended screen, however audio will not transition over to the TV. I've gone into sound settings, selected "HDMI/Display Port 2" however testing audio does not fire.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amd driver is not recogmended even for gaming, it's a workstation driver created for workstation graphical purposes. Uninstall it and stick to using the Opensource driver. Open a terminal and type
sudo amdconfig --uninstall
if the driver is installed on the distribution files rather than xorg, it will give you another command like "dpkg -r amdcccle" and you take that command and use it with sudo. One the uninstallation is done, reboot and all your sound devices should be back in the sound settings.

Comment: Thanks! Thats strange, it wasn't working prior to the installation which is why i decided to go ahead and install it. 

Anyways all is well now, thanks!

Comment: No problem, ive been dealing with amd linux my whole life. Accept my answer to close the question.

Comment: please mark my answer as "accepted" by pressing the checkmark so i could move on

Comment: Whoops, thought i did! Apologize for that delay!